# How to change the location of webroot in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to keep the webroot folder at the actual root?

To explain: what should I do to achieve a folder structure like this:

```
app/
cake/
css/
files/
img/
js/
plugins/
vendors/
```

With everything working as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing **mistake of exposing your code to public**.

```
/project/
/project/app/ 
...
/project/css/
/project/js/
...
```

However if you still want to set `/project/` as your webroot, place this into `.htaccess` file

```
// /project/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Recommendation:** You should stick to the default directory structure of CakePHP, because it's **proven** secure and best practice to do most kind of applications.

Comment: Why is putting images, scripts and css files in the webroot a mistake? Where is the security problem?

Comment: If you set `/project/` as webroot, then `/project/app/` can be browsed  simply accessing this `http://example.com/app/AppController.php` or  `http://example.com/app/models/User.php` which you really not want to be browsed like that.

Comment: Well, ok, that makes sense ;] if I type `http://example.com/images/` into the address bar, it goes to `http://example.com/app/webroot/images` - is there a way to fix that?

Comment: make sure you have `/project/images/` created. its the 1st rule in htaccess file.

Comment: This will work, but please heed this poster's advice: exposing your code within webroot is a Bad Idea.  Putting statics inside the web root is a necessity, but putting secure php code inside hte webroot is dangerous because your site is likely to get hacked.  In particular, you should avoid posting your site's URL anywhere related to this thread.  Security by obscurity is better than no security at all.

Comment: Btw @PawelMysior, you can get the precise functionality you requested by referring to my answer below.  Symlinks are the standard way of doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want your workflow to be simplified, with top-level access to the directories you use frequently.  However, it isn't wise to have your main sourcecode inside the web root.

You can instead use [symlinks](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/suse-linux/41640-how-create-symlink.html) to link to the static folders (`css`, `img`, `js`, etc).